How to change the mouse cursor when a widget in Flutter is drag (and drop)?
in Flutter I have a LongPressDraggable.
I want to change my cursor to a SystemMouseCursors.grabbing when I’m grabbing and moving around the widget how to do this?
I tried to set ignoringFeedbackPointer to false and added a MouseRegion to the feedback widget and this created the behavior I wanted but I can't drop the widget anymore. the ignoringFeedbackPointer seems to get in the way of the dropping part.
